# Swift Game Center save high score function not working

Tags: ios, swift, function, save, game-center

I'm trying to add game center functionality to my app and this my function to take the user's high score and put in onto the leader board.  The problem is it only uploads the first high score.  I call it again when the user gets a new high score but it does work.

```
//send high score to leaderboard
    func saveHighscore(score:Int)
    {
        //check if user is signed in
        if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated
        {
            let scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "774433bbcc11bbvv") //leaderboard id here
            scoreReporter.value = Int64(circleView1.score) //score variable here (same as above)
            let scoreArray: [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]
            GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray,withCompletionHandler: {(error : NSError?) -> Void in
                if error != nil
                {
                    print("error")
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to replace the block with the completion handler from this:

```
GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray,withCompletionHandler: {(error : NSError?) -> Void in
    if error != nil
    {
        print("error")
    }
})
```

to this:

```
GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray) {(error) in
    self.lastError = error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you used NSUserDefaults to save and update the new highScore when the Game is over.

```
***Game Scene***
var defaults = NSUserDefaults()
var score:Int = 0
var highScore:Int = 0

func saveHighScore(score:Int) {
    //Check If User is Signed In
    if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {

        let scoreReporter = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "774433bbcc11bbvv") 
        scoreReporter.value = Int64(score)
        let scoreArray: [GKScore] = [scoreReporter]
        GKScore.reportScores(scoreArray, withCompletionHandler: {(error : NSError?) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print("error")
            }
        })

    }

}
```

**Game Over**
//Get High Score

```
let highScore =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highScore")

if (score > highScore){                 

    defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "highScore") 

}
```

**Game Over**
// Save Score To Leaderboard

```
    saveHighScore(score)
```